# Find the most representative samples from a class

Tags: data-mining

I have a dataset where each sample has 187 dimensions. The normal class has 70.000 samples while the other 4 have at most 5.000. Ideally, I would like to keep at most 15000 samples from the normal class which are representative enough. In other words I want to discard redundant samples from the normal class keeping the most beneficial ones.
Has anyone tried something similar?

Comment: Hi, I would like to recommend you to use this code for your purpose: https://github.com/BeenKim/MMD-critic
In this paper, they selected the representatives from a large amount of data.

Comment: Thank you the paper seems useful and with a lot of relevant references included.

Comment: Im glad it helps!