# How to subset a 'representative sample'?

Tags: sampling

Sometimes I need to subsample a dataset for my analysis/modelling. What are the strategies/things to check for to select a subsample that's representative of the entire sample? And in addition, how to evaluate the 'representativeness' of the subset taken?

I visited [this post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/102060/how-create-a-representative-small-subset-from-a-huge-dataset-for-local-developm), but I think its focus is on reducing the volume of the data instead of getting a qualitatively representative sample of the larger set. Besides, I'm asking for non-time series data, which is something more general.

I also visited [this post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/73641/find-the-most-representative-samples-from-a-class), but find it not that relevant.

It would be nice to hear how things are done in (industrial) practice. TIA.

Comment: As mentioned in the first post for non-sequential data, have you tried simply sampling random rows from the dataset?

Comment: @Oxbowerce, thanks for the recommendation. I've edited the question to reflect what I truly want to ask for, in addition to how to sample, also how to evaluate. Thanks for your inputs :)